# filter array of object by taking two object with same date

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to filter an array of objects on some conditions as:

```
filtered_shifts = myShifts.filter{$0.regionName == region && $0.cityName == city && $0.idNationality == idn && $0.quantityStaff != 0 && $0.shiftDate > todaydate}
```

I want to filter it more so if there is a shiftType == "night" and shiftType == "day" for the same shiftDate then added to my filtered shifts array.

> if there is  shift type = day AND type = night for same date then add it to my filtered array

how can i achieve this?

**FOR EXAMPLE**

Lets say that

```
   myShifts = {
       "id": 50,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 2,
        "id_nationality": 3,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "day",
        "weekday": "wed",
        "quantity_staff": 5,
        "lead_hours": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-05-13 16:27:21",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-13 16:27:21",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Khobar",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    },
    {
        "id": 70,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 1,
        "id_nationality": 3,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "day",
        "weekday": "wed",
        "quantity_staff": 12,
        "lead_hours": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Dammam",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    },
    {
        "id": 74,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 1,
        "id_nationality": 3,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "night",
        "weekday": "wed",
        "quantity_staff": 20,
        "lead_hours": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Dammam",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 1,
        "id_nationality": 4,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-05-15 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "night",
        "weekday": "tue",
        "quantity_staff": 5,
        "lead_hours": 2,
        "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:46:20",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-15 10:33:29",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Dammam",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    }
```

I want:

```
 filtered_Shifts =  {
        "id": 70,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 1,
        "id_nationality": 3,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "day",
        "weekday": "wed",
        "quantity_staff": 12,
        "lead_hours": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Dammam",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    },
    {
        "id": 74,
        "id_region": 1,
        "id_city": 1,
        "id_nationality": 3,
        "id_service": 1,
        "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
        "shift_type": "night",
        "weekday": "wed",
        "quantity_staff": 20,
        "lead_hours": 3,
        "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "city_name": "Dammam",
        "region_name": "Eastren"
    },
```

cuz in date 2018-06-06 there is shift_type = night AND day ...

Comment: Please share your sample array with objects

Comment: @PPL just did .. please check it out

Comment: Is there any possible value of `shift_type` other than **night** and **day**?

Comment: @nayem no .....

Comment: you can first check for night and day  condition if true then use you above condition.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan how to check if theres day and night for same date?

Comment: Well, then you don't need to check for `shift_type` at all. If your filter satisfies the `shift_date` condition you are good to go.

Comment: @nayem i need only shifts where shift_date has two shift_type day and night .. how i don't need to check shift_type?

Comment: first get array of dates unique it and iterate it on your object array.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan cannot get unique dates when it should be two one for day and one for night

Comment: i am doing it for you :) wait.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan ok :D

Comment: check My Answer @mrs.bassim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

struct MyShifts: Codable {
    let id :Int
    let id_region: Int
    let id_city: Int
    let id_nationality: Int
    let id_service: Int
    let shift_date: String
    let shift_type: String
    let weekday: String
    let quantity_staff : Int
    let lead_hours: Int
    let created_at: String
    let updated_at: String
    let deleted_at:String
    let city_name: String
    let region_name: String
}



let myShifts = """
[{
"id": 50,
"id_region": 1,
"id_city": 2,
"id_nationality": 3,
"id_service": 1,
"shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
"shift_type": "day",
"weekday": "wed",
"quantity_staff": 5,
"lead_hours": 3,
"created_at": "2018-05-13 16:27:21",
"updated_at": "2018-05-13 16:27:21",
"deleted_at": "2018-05-13 16:27:21",
"city_name": "Khobar",
"region_name": "Eastren"
    },
{
    "id": 70,
    "id_region": 1,
    "id_city": 1,
    "id_nationality": 3,
    "id_service": 1,
    "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
    "shift_type": "day",
    "weekday": "wed",
    "quantity_staff": 12,
    "lead_hours": 3,
    "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:03:02",
    "deleted_at": "2018-05-15 10:33:29",
    "city_name": "Dammam",
    "region_name": "Eastren"
},
{
    "id": 74,
    "id_region": 1,
    "id_city": 1,
    "id_nationality": 3,
    "id_service": 1,
    "shift_date": "2018-06-06 00:00:00",
    "shift_type": "night",
    "weekday": "wed",
    "quantity_staff": 20,
    "lead_hours": 3,
    "created_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-21 14:40:56",
    "deleted_at": "2018-05-15 10:33:29",
    "city_name": "Dammam",
    "region_name": "Eastren"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "id_region": 1,
    "id_city": 1,
    "id_nationality": 4,
    "id_service": 1,
    "shift_date": "2018-05-15 00:00:00",
    "shift_type": "night",
    "weekday": "tue",
    "quantity_staff": 5,
    "lead_hours": 2,
    "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:46:20",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-15 10:33:29",
    "deleted_at": "2018-05-15 10:33:29",
    "city_name": "Dammam",
    "region_name": "Eastren"
}]
""".data(using: .utf8)! // our native (JSON) data

let myShiftsObjectArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyShifts].self, from: myShifts) // decoding our data
myShiftsObjectArray.forEach { print($0) } // decoded!
var Dates = Set<String>()
var uniqueArray = [MyShifts]()
for shift in myShiftsObjectArray {
    if !Dates.contains(shift.shift_date) {
        uniqueArray.append(shift)
        Dates.insert(shift.shift_date)
    }
}

print(uniqueArray.count)
var NewFilteredShifts = NSMutableArray()
for loop in uniqueArray
{
    for loopAll in myShiftsObjectArray
    {
        if loop.shift_date == loopAll.shift_date && !NewFilteredShifts.contains(loopAll)
        {
             if loopAll.region_name == "Eastren" && loopAll.city_name == "Dammam" && loopAll.id_nationality == 4 && loopAll.quantity_staff != 0 && (loopAll.shift_type == "day" || loopAll.shift_type == "night")
            {
                NewFilteredShifts.add(loopAll)

            }
        }

    }
}
print(NewFilteredShifts)
```

I hope This will help you out.

Comment: you have to do some changes according to your need this will work fine :)

Comment: there is one mistake i am updating it

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I fixed it as needed and its perfect! :)

Comment: My pleasure HappyCoding.

Comment: ummm ... when first tried it .. it was working just fine .. i may mistook that ..
am getting the same result as i was before .. 
maybe the mistake you mentioned?

Comment: but i need NewFilteredShifts = NSMutableArray() of type Shift to see if its correct or not...

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: that's okay .. no not yet :(

Comment: it should work man can you send me your updated code with mine logic ?